# How can I get the creation date of an Excel File in a Python script?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I am currently creating a script to automate the treatment of some Excel files. I am working on Excel (.xlsx) files and modifying them with the library Pandas. I need to get the creation date of one of those files so I can insert it into another file and I don't have the slightest clue on how to proceed.

I am currently using Python 3.3.5, Pandas 0.15.2 and I can't use any library not currently in Spyder (I work in a big company where we aren't allowed to update versions or to install anything not approved first and approving something takes months)

---

**UPDATE:** `2022-07-29`

> This is not a duplicate as it explicitly mentions the creation date of an Excel file. This info is **metadata** inside the Excel file and not shown in the OS file creation data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solution and the answer to the question could be easily found by googling for simple tutorial on python and files management.

Comment: see this [get creation date of file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's very helpful
Sorry I hadn't the right keywords

Comment: This is not a duplicate as it explicitly mentions the creation date of an Excel file. This info is meta data to the Excel file and not shown in the OS file creation data.